# how do i make a div place over another and make it responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive-images

I'm trying to copy a design and I'm having trouble with one thing which is this bit right here:
[image]

i know its a div with another div containing text and another containing an image,

like so :

```
<div class="container">
<div class="container">text</div>
<divclass="container">image</div>
</div>
```

one thing I can try to make it responsive is to use percentages but I can't use them on the images directly, I need a way to implement something like this and make it scaleable.

Comment: look into the `position`-attribute. In this case, a combination of `position: absolute` and `position: relative` is used. In special cases, a `negative margin` can achieve similar effects.

Answer (score 0):

Enough to make it relative, then on desktop you can nudge it a bit. (test it on full page)

```css
.half {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .half {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .nudged {
    top: +100px;
    left: -100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="half">text</div>
  <div class="half nudged">image</div>
</div>
clear the float
```